# How to use CSS :first-of-type selector ignoring non-displayed elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, first-of-type

I'm making a table-like layout on page where I can remove rows. I only want the row labels to show when they are for the first row and so I have used the `:first-of-type` CSS selector to display them and then have hidden all the other labels else. A simplified version of the html roughly looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <label>Name</label>
       <input></input>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <label>Name</label>
       <input></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a simplified CSS like this:

```
.row label {
    display:none;
}
.row:first-of-type label {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This works fine except when I set the first row to `display:none` it still considers the un-displayed row the first-of-type and so the labels don't show in the row that is displayed. This all uses JQuery and so I suppose I could dynamically add and remove a `.first-row` class but I was hoping for something more elegant using CSS. Any ideas? I don't think you can do a `:not()` selector based on a style value can you?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had seen those other questions but I was hoping first-of-type worked a little different than nth-child or that there was an un-perused area with :not().